# C string RSA public key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

One question about the public key. 
If I am using C code to do some RSA stuff, do I need to put "\r\n" or "\n" at the end of each line?

Should I write a C string like this?

"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n" MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCU+1bLfPmcY7qrF/dTbAtuJlv4R/FVc1WEH9HK\r\n" U0jQjX/n/db9vz/x0i3te/bKLNEcwUhBu+PWPnOt/qVURG9BUT6RsCRFUn0CyGiUKoy45o9K/mJA\r\n" HmbrNtrUB6ckrYLF75Y50nUNsBVHUDw8yQymmiOBT1gc/KM5s1xTz44LMwIDAQAB\r\n"
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n";

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's PEM format, see [RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.3.2.2):

> PEM canonicalization assures that the message text is represented
> with the ASCII character set and `"<CR><LF>"` line delimiters

So that would translate into `\r\n` of course.

Comment: Correct answer, as usual. I just added a link to the RFC.